# same time mapping two props in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am stucked in a problem where I have two kind of props and need to map them in same option. Below is my code.

```
{this.props.languageInitials.map((langInitial, i) =>
   (<option key={i} value={langInitial}>this.props.fullLanguageName[i]</option>)
)}
```

Here I have language initials plus language full names in two different props. Language initials I can map but If I use second one then it is null.

Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Always simply update your question with more information, don't paste it in the comments (Especially if it's code)

Comment: Are you sure `this.props.fullLanguageName` has the same length as `this.props.languageInitials`?

Comment: yes I am sure both has the same length. And it is 27

Comment: In your example. `this.props.fullLanguageName[i]` should be: `{this.props.fullLanguageName[i]}`. Also, I'm not sure what your code structure looks like, but it probably makes more sense to have both values on the same object, like so: `languages: [{ initial: 'En', fullName: 'English' }, { initial: 'Sp', fullName: 'Spanish' }]` This would allow you to access them much easier.

Comment: Thanks alot NorianNyx!! that really helped me out and my problem is solved.